# Why is apalike bibliographystyle (and more generally author-date styles) so rare in mathematics?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle, mathematics

I hope that this question is appropriate for this forum -- I don't really know where else to ask it, and I think it is at least relevant to the expertise of the users of this site.

I often find that when I read papers I spend a lot of time checking the bibliography to see what paper people are referring to when they cite using the plain bibliographystyle. Even if they use a style that contains more information than just a number in the label, it isn't always obvious what they mean. For example, [Art20] could be Artin 1920 or Arthur 2020 (admittedly this isn't very realistic since you would definitely know from context, but I'm more concerned about the information lost when there are multiple authors -- it takes a while to remember what [GGPS67] is).

For this reason, I really appreciate it when authors use a labeling style that includes the author's full last name and date (for example in Elkies' online notes, e.g. [http://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M229.18/disc.pdf](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eelkies/M229.18/disc.pdf)). Why are citation styles like this so rare in mathematics? Is there a good reason not to use them?

Comment: imho this is off topic and opinion based. You would have to ask on some math site.

Comment: One reason, at least in computer science, is page limits for conference submissions (numeric or abbreviated citations are shorter than author-year, especially with a lot of authors). Readability is also better if a sentence or paragraph contains a lot of citations. But indeed it is off-topic, you can try at [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), or maybe on [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about TeX/LaTeX or related technologies.

Comment: Another possible reason (from Academia.SE) is that mathematicians "don't care" about citation style (https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/74729/why-do-some-fields-care-so-much-more-about-citation-styles). Your question would be on topic there as well I guess.